# How to run multiple commands in bash script if my condition is true

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

```
a=Y
b=Y
c=Y


if condition like $a=='y' then execute all this statements******  
cat *.tar.gz | tar -xzvf - -i  
echo "5"  
tar -xvf *.tar.gz   
echo "9"  
rm -rf *.tar.gz  

elif($b=='y') condition ***   
cp $source $destination  
cp $source/conf/* $destination/conf

else (**** )
some commands
```

Comment: Is the question about how to write basic bash syntax? There are tons of tutorials out there ...

Comment: what i actually want is to run multiple commands if condition is true otherwise skip all those commands, in all the tutorials i am getting that u can olny run one command after if holds true.

Comment: I don't believe you looked. Here's one https://serverfault.com/a/216431/267016

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct syntax for \`if...elif\` statements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266359/correct-syntax-for-if-elif-statements)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard form of an `if`-statement is

```
if condition; then
    action
    action
    ...
elif condition; then
    action
    action
    ...
else
    action
    action
    ...
fi
```

where the `elif` and `else` branches are optional and where there may be multiple `elif` branches.

In your case:

```
if [ "$a" = "y" ]; then
    cat *.tar.gz | tar -xzvf - -i  
    echo "5"  
    tar -xvf *.tar.gz   
    echo "9"  
    rm -rf *.tar.gz
elif [ "$b" = "y" ]; then
    cp "$source" "$destination"  
    cp "$source"/conf/* "$destination"/conf   
else
    some commands
fi
```

I have not looked at the actual commands that you want to execute here, and whether they make sense.

Comment: Okay thnx, that was just a dummy commands, it worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in `GNU Make 4.2.1` (using `SHELL=/bin/bash`)

Comment: @artu-hnrq A Makefile is not a shell script. See e.g. [How to write bash script in Makefile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255743) or [How to write exactly bash scripts into Makefiles?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270778) or [Iterate bash associative array in Makefile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232436)